# Solving SDE: $\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=(c+\sigma_wW(t))y(t)+\epsilon(t) $ in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, stochastic-calculus

I want to solve this differential equation $\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=(c+\sigma_w W(t))y(t)+\epsilon(t) $. For details see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385633/solving-sde-fracdytdt-c-sigma-wwtyt-epsilont. My approach is using *Mathematica*. However, I have not been able to specify this SDE in *Mathematica*. As far as I understand, the `ItoProcess` function is appropriate. I have come this far:

```
proc = 
  ItoProcess[
     {\[DifferentialD]y[t] == c*y[t]\[DifferentialD]t + 
       e[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + σ*y[t]*w[t]}, 
     y[t], {y, y0}, t, Distributed[w, WienerProcess[]]]
```

How do I now tell *Mathematica* that `e[t]` is a gaussian white noise process, `c` is a scalar and `σ` a non-negative scalar?

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for related problems ?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

**Revision to accommodate multiple random processes**

One approach is to define `e[t]` in the question as `e*\[DifferentialD]w[t]`, with `e` a scale factor.

Then, `ItoProcess` yields

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]y[t] == c*y[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + σ*y[t]
    *\[DifferentialD]w1[t] + e*\[DifferentialD]w2[t]}, y[t], {y, y0}, t, 
    {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]
```

or, equivalently,

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]y[t] == y[t]*\[DifferentialD]w1[t] + 
    \[DifferentialD]w2[t]}, y[t], {y, y0}, t, 
    {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[c, σ], w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, e]}]

(* ItoProcess[{{c y[t]}, {{σ y[t], e}}, y[t]}, {{y}, {y0}}, {t, 0}] *)
```

A typical result can be obtained by specifying the four parameters.

```
SeedRandom[1236];
ans = RandomFunction[proc /. {σ -> 0.1, y0 -> 1, c -> -0.01, e -> 0.1}, {0, 100, .1}];
ListLinePlot[ans, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, y}]
```

[image]

Note that `SeedRandom` is included only to obtain this particular curve and otherwise is unnecessary.

Comment: If I do this, are the first w[t] and second w[t] then independent or one and the same process?
Are you sure that all constants have to be given numerical values? I have examples notebooks where this is not the case and they work just fine.

Comment: @JulianKarls  You are correct that giving all constants numerical values is not needed to define an `ItoProcess` but only to obtain numerical results.  Also, I have revised the answer above to introduce a second `WienerProcess` to represent e(t).  Thanks for prompting me to be more careful.

Comment: Great, this has solved putting the process into mathematica. Is there a function that gives me the analytic expression for $y(t)$?

Comment: @JulianKarls  There is no analytic expression for `y[t]`, because it is stochastic.  However, you can obtain its average value from `Mean[proc[t]]`, which is `E^(c t) y0`.  If the answer above meets you needs, please do not forget to accept it.  Best wishes.

Comment: `y[t]` being stochastic does not mean that there does not exist an analytic expression for it. The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process for example is represented by a very similar SDE and there exists an analytic expression for it.

Comment: @JulianKarls  I cannot answer this question.  Sorry.

Comment: I think you are missing the `\[DifferentialD]t` on the term involving w1

Comment: @JulianKarls  What do you think the expression should be, and how does it change the answer?

Comment: The expression should be `proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]y[t] == 
    c*y[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + \[Sigma]*
      y[t]*\[DifferentialD]w1[t]*\[DifferentialD]t + 
     e*\[DifferentialD]w2[t]}, y[t], {y, y0}, 
  t, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]` If I do this, I get the error that `The specification [...] is not a random process recognized by the system. >>`  when i call RandomFucntion. So mathematica might not be able to solve this?

Comment: @JulianKarls  `RandomFunction[proc /. {σ -> 0.1, y0 -> 1, c -> -0.01, e -> 0.1}, {0, 100, .1}]; ListLinePlot[ans, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All,     AxesLabel -> {t, y}]` crashes with your definition of `proc`.

Comment: I know but thats the correct translation of the SDE that I am trying to solve.

Comment: I am uncertain whether the expression you gave today is a legitimate Ito process.  However, I am not an expert on this topic, and you might do well to consult an expert.  Best wishes.